# Mortal Kombat Storyline - what happened?

Tags: mortal-kombat

Mortal Kombat TV series end with every earthrelm hero dieing and Raiden is taken prisoner and is forced to observe as Earthrealm falls under Shao Kahn's rule.

In Mortal Kombat X the game, there are multiple factions, everyone lives again and there's no mention of Goro, Motaro and a few other big animals, while Shao'Kan is presented to be dead, just as some of the Cyber-like members.

So what exactly happened in between ?
How did Raiden get free, how the rest got undead, what killed Shao'Kan and what happened to Goro & Co. ?

Comment: Totally different continuities, as I understand it. The show is based on the games, but the games ignore the show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video game *Mortal Kombat X* is a sequel to *Mortal Kombat 9* (2011), a "reboot" (or rather a "reset") of the franchise (or rather "timeline"). It has nothing to do with a TV show.

I recommend you play it, as it basicly [retells the story of *MK1*, *MK2* and *MK3*.](http://mortalkombat.wikia.com/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_%282011%29%27s_Story_Mode) And then play *MKX*. For spoilers and more detailed information on why and how these people are alive (or not), you can read the story summary I've linked.

Comment: I recommend everyone plays [Mortal Kombat Trilogy](http://86bb71d19d3bcb79effc-d9e6924a0395cb1b5b9f03b7640d26eb.r91.cf1.rackcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/mortal-kombat-trilogy-character-select-screenshot.jpg). It should be mandatory!

Comment: @Daft don't hurt me mate :( I am so bad at fighting games I struggled to beat the campaign of Injustice: Gods Among Us on medium.... I've been a gamer since for the past 17 years, I've beaten more games than I can possibly remember, and my non-gamer girlfriend is capable of kicking my ass in Injustice and Skullgirls (after I've beaten the campaign, and she hasn't played it... ever)... I don't even want to think how playing MK would end up for me.

Comment: There's no shame in it! I always considered myself one of the best MK players in the history of the universe. Until I played my first match online...

Comment: And on top of having my ass handed to me, I got to enjoy some 14yr old explaining in graphic detail, his escapades with my mother the night before.

Comment: @Daft the truest on-line experience. And people wonder why I prefer singleplayer/mute play/playing in closed teams on TeamSpeak

Comment: thanks peter for the link to storyline. I did play Mk1 2 and 3 but a very long time ago and I don't remember their storylines.

Comment: @Overmind there are some changes, though. Minor, but still.